# Subtracting DateValue: "Run-time error 430: Class does not support automation or does not support expected interface"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract the mails of last 10 days from Outlook to Excel using VBA.

I am targeting a sub folder under Inbox named BD_Invoice where mails are gathered by following rules.

While running the VBA it is showing

> Run-time error 430: Class does not support automation or does not support expected interface

```vb
Option Explicit
'This Code is Downloaded from OfficeTricks.com
'Visit this site for more such Free Code
Sub VBA_Export_Outlook_Emails_To_Excel()
    'Add Tools->References->"Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library"
    'nn.n varies as per our Outlook Installation
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim sFolders As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim iRow As Integer, oRow As Integer
    Dim MailBoxName As String, Pst_Folder_Name  As String
    
    'Mailbox or PST Main Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
    MailBoxName = "MY_MAIL_ID"
 
    'Mailbox Folder or PST Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
    Pst_Folder_Name = "BD_Invoice" 'Sample "Inbox" or "Sent Items"
 
    'To directly a Folder at a high level
    'Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)
    
    'To access a main folder or a subfolder (level-1)
    For Each Folder In Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders
        If VBA.UCase(Folder.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then GoTo Label_Folder_Found
        For Each sFolders In Folder.Folders
            If VBA.UCase(sFolders.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then
                Set Folder = sFolders
                GoTo Label_Folder_Found
            End If
        Next sFolders
    Next Folder

Label_Folder_Found:
     If Folder.Name = "" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
        GoTo End_Lbl1:
    End If
 
    'Read Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Folder.Items.Sort "Received"
    
    'Insert Column Headers
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4) = "Size"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5) = "EmailID"
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 6) = "Body"
    
    'Export eMail Data from PST Folder to Excel with date and time
    oRow = 1
    For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count
        'If condition to import mails received in last 60 days
        'To import all emails, comment or remove this IF condition
        If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) <= 5 Then
           oRow = oRow + 1
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1).Select
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 2) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 3) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 4) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Size
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
           'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 6) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
        End If
    Next iRow
    MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"
    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set sFolders = Nothing
    
End_Lbl1:
End Sub
```

I am using Office 365.

---

The problem is shown at

```vb
If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) <= 10
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Where do you get this error?

Comment: @Shrotter I cannot debugged it. The problem is shown at - 

```If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) <= 10 Then```

Comment: The `DateValue()` function returns a string so you cannot deduct a string from another string.